# How to programmatically mimic latency between server and client in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a test script for nodejs. The test case look like this:

```js
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');

// Here is server
var server = http.createSever(function (req, res) {
   res.end('ok');
}).listen();

var port = server.address().port;

// Here is client
var numRequest = 20;
var client = net.connect({port: port, allowHalfOpen: true});
for (var i = 0; i < numRequest; i++) {
    client.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' + 'Host: some.host.name\r\n' + '\r\n\r\n');
}
client.end();
```

Since both the server and the client runs on my local machine, the server receives the request immediately. However, I want to mimic the scenario, where the server receives the request after a period of time. In particular, I want to mimic the scenario, the http connection is closed before server receives all the request. So, the question is, how to programmatically mimic such a scenario? Thx :)

Comment: how about adding sleep function in server/client ?
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

await sleep(2000)

Comment: Easiest solution is not to do this in the server, but in the browser devtools: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#throttling

Comment: @Bergi He says node.js, not browser. Does this work in node.js with devtools too? I highly doubt that.  If you want just to delay the connection, a simple `setTimeout()` is fine.

Comment: @Marc Ah, right, I had not realised the client was written with node.js too

Comment: @newbie Thx for your reply. I want to mimic the latency between server and client so that I can close the http connection before the server receives all the request. I doubt adding sleep function cannot address my problem.